# Question on XPathNodeIterator Issue in C#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, xpathnodeiterator

I am parsing an Xml file. and I got a trouble on how to use `XPathNodeIterator` `MoveNext()` more reasonable in C#2.0.

My code as this,

```
while (it.MoveNext())
{


string str = it.Current.GetAttribute("id", it.Current.NamespaceURI);

it.Current.MoveToChild("item", "");

// do someting....
// My XMl file is a complex Xml file. I must Move to multi layer Child with *MoveToChild()*.
// After that, I must add several *MoveToParent()* in different Layers to make sure the *it* still meet for the use of while loop.
// I think it doesn't make sense like this.
// Some time. the *it* can't still direct to my original layer. While-Loop doesn't work well.

}
```

I tried to declare a new XPathNodeIterator object *tempIt* as this,

```
while (it.MoveNext())
{

    XPathNodeIterator tempIt;
    tempIt= it;

    string str = tempIt.Current.GetAttribute("id", tempIt.Current.NamespaceURI);

    tempIt.Current.MoveToChild("item", "");

    // Now I chech *it* on here, I found the *it* also changed it's *current* and "position". and it's count also changed. 
    // I don't know why.

}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Appreciated for you comments and suggestions.

Comment: You've created an xpathnodeiterator and then you're using DOM-style navigation - use the select method and learn xpath. You only need one iterator.

Comment: @ annakata . Yes, I'd better change to use XPath *select* method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that can help

```
while (nodeIterator.MoveNext())
{
    XPathNavigator n = nodeIterator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(n.LocalName);
}


XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("books.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/bookstore/book");
nodes.MoveNext();
XPathNavigator nodesNavigator = nodes.Current;

XPathNodeIterator nodesText = nodesNavigator.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Text, false);

while (nodesText.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(nodesText.Current.Value);
```

and books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<bookstore>
    <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
        <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
            <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
        </author>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
    <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967-11-17" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
        <title>The Confidence Man</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Herman</first-name>
            <last-name>Melville</last-name>
        </author>
        <price>11.99</price>
    </book>
    <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991-02-15" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
        <title>The Gorgias</title>
        <author>
            <name>Plato</name>
        </author>
        <price>9.99</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```